# How can I select a whole line of text from where my cursor is (VB)?

Tags: select, textbox, line

I need to select the whole line from where the cursor already is in textbox1. Once I have done this I can then use it for a command. Thanks

I have only been able to find the following code:

```
Dim MyArr
            MyArr = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)
```

Thats it so far, can someone please help me?

Comment: can you please post the code you currently have

Comment: @EmmanuelN I have added in the code, but there isn't much there :(

Comment: Use richtextbox instead of textbox

Answer (score 0):

Use [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx), [GetLineFromCharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex.aspx), and [Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) to get line text.

Something like:

```
Dim lineText As String  = MyTextBox.Lines(MyTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(MyTextBox.SelectionStart))
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work? can you give me a whole sub please?